# How do I wire a mini split that requires 208-230V with a 15A breaker, but came only with single pole wiring?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, mini-split

I am installing a Rovsun 12,000 BTU mini-split with heat pump. The voltage range is 208V-230V. The wiring for the unit consists of L1 Black hot wire, L2 White neutral wire, and the green ground wire. How do I wire this system to supply the voltage needed without 2 pole wiring?

Answer (score 13):

The white wire is almost certainly not neutral. L1 and L2 should be the two legs of 240V, each side of the split phase. The device needs no neutral. If you can link to the manual, I can confirm this, but I would be very surprised if it worked any other way.

Answer (score 8):

In [North American split-phase power](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4), 240V Mini-splits take both hot wires. They can't use neutral.

They don't make cables with red, black and no white.  You are expected to buy a roll of red tape and re-mark the white wire red.

I'm not even half kidding; the marking is mandatory but you don't have to use red - black will do.   Really, in 120/240V split-phase power there's no useful purpose in distinguishing the two hot wires from each other.   (it matters in 3-phase because it affects motor rotation).

Comment: And not needing to remark is one of the reasons I love THHN nowadays.